# How to include textarea field when defining model of a contact us form in react web application

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to describe a model for a contact us form. This form will have two text fields and one textarea field which will be used for the message. I have defined the message field as type: "textarea" but when it is rendered it is showing up as a normal text field. Can anyone suggest how to define textarea field here?

This is for a simple contact us form in reactjs.

```
  <DynamicForm className="contactform"
  title = "Contact us"
  model = {[
    {key: "name", label: "Name", props: {required:true}},
    {key: "email", label: "E-mail", type:"email"},
    {key: "message", label: "Message", type: "textarea" }
  ]}
  onSubmit = {(model) => {this.onSubmit(model)}}

  />
```

I expect that a textarea will render when I give type as textarea in the above code.

Dynamic Form is defined here :

'''

```
import React from 'react';
import './contact.css';

export default class DynamicForm extends React.Component {
state = {
}
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.onSubmit) this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
}

onChange = (e, key) => {
    this.setState({
        [key]: this[key]
    })

}

renderForm = () => {
    let model = this.props.model;
    let formUI = model.map((m) => {
        let key = m.key;
        let type = m.type || "text";
        let props = m.props || {};
        return (
            <div key={key} className="form-group">
                <label className="formlabel"
                    key={"l" + m.key}
                    htmlFor={m.key}>
                    {m.label}
                </label>
                <input {...props}
                    ref={(key) => { this[m.key] = key }}
                    className="form-input"
                    type={type}
                    key={"i" + m.key}
                    onChange={(e) => { this.onChange(e, key) }}
                >
                </input>
            </div>
        )
    });
    return formUI;
}

render() {
    let title = this.props.title || "Dynamic Contact Us Form";
    return (
        <div className={this.props.className}>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <form className="dynamic-form" onSubmit={(e) => this.onSubmit(e)}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    {this.renderForm()}
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>


            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

'''

Comment: Where is your `DynamicForm` component coming from ?

Comment: Just added the DynamicForm component above

Comment: Hi @ArnaudChrist please let me know if you want me to provide any other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textarea` is [not a valid type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types) of the `input` type.

You should instead use the [`textarea` HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).

Here is something that could work:

```
renderForm = () => {
    let model = this.props.model;
    let formUI = model.map((m) => {
        let key = m.key;
        let type = m.type || "text";
        let props = m.props || {};
        return (
            <div key={key} className="form-group">
                <label className="formlabel"
                    key={"l" + m.key}
                    htmlFor={m.key}>
                    {m.label}
                </label>
                {type === "textarea" ? 
                  (<textarea [Add here the textarea props]>)
                :
                  (<input {...props}
                    ref={(key) => { this[m.key] = key }}
                    className="form-input"
                    type={type}
                    key={"i" + m.key}
                    onChange={(e) => { this.onChange(e, key) }}
                  >)}
                </input>
            </div>
        )
    });
    return formUI;
}
```

Comment: If I add textarea element in the above return statement under input field it displays text area 3 times, where should I add the textarea html element so I can keep the existing text fields of name and email alongwith displaying text area for the message part.

Comment: I am learning, will really appreciate your help if you can guide me in the right direction, please.

Comment: You have to put a condition to know which element (of `input` or `textarea`) you have to render. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Great that worked. Thank You. Seem like I have hit another wall infront of me as the following error appeared because of circular structure of JSON TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLInputElement'
    |     property '__reactInternalInstance$ce62b1v9p0n' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    --- property 'stateNode' closes the circle

Comment: It is because of the following code 

<pre style={{width:"300px"}}>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}
      </pre>

Comment: As this is not linked to your initial question, I propose you to create a new one if you are blocked. This may help other users with the same problem to retrieve it in the future.

Comment: Here is the related question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665437/how-to-fix-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json-in-my-simple-reactjs